# Force connector built with Devkit to have a unique name at runtime

Tags: mule, mule-studio, devkit

How do you force a connector built with Devkit to have a unique name at runtime in a Mule Application? Ie other connectors like http don't allow duplicate names.

Ie I don't wont to allow a flow like this:

```
<FooConnector:config name="foo" doc:name="foo"/>
<FooConnector:config name="foo" doc:name="foo"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the uniqueness of a DevKit connector declaration is not enforced, neither at schema level nor at Mule registry level.

IMO this is a bug so I reported it: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/DEVKIT-426

Comment: ok thanks, but we find that in our project Mule Studio runs it and shows no errors.

Comment: Wow, that is a bug IMO. And what about in Mule? Does the app start too? This is scary stuff.